# Why my app be labeled as 'Autogenerated'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-audience-network, facebook-monetization-manager

in facebook monetization manager, after create property and the default first placement, the system will auto establish an app on facebook developer, labeled 'XX - MM', but today follow the same operation, I find my new app be labeled as 'XX - Autogenerated', a serious thing: the url of the app on facebook developer be broken, cannot visit it.

here the abnormal app looks like:

[image]

when I try to visit it on facebook developer, only get 'Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.'

I want to know why cause this, and how to recover normal? thanks

Comment: hi Xun, any chance you still have that broken link?

Comment: hi, Fallen, Facebook update so soon, I never meet above thing anymore. And later I have to revert my workflow on ads creation: first create app on facebook developer, then add audience network product, finally move to monetization manager, the system will auto generate property on monetization manager.